# "ImportError: cannot import name 'key' from 'secrets'"

Tags: python

I am trying to import my API key from another file into my init.py file, but I keep getting this error in the terminal, "**ImportError: cannot import name 'key' from 'secrets'**" here is my code:

init.py

```
from secrets import key

    res2 = requests.get(API_BASE_URL,
                                params={'key': key, 'location': location})
            location_coordinates = res2.json()
```

I have stored my key in another file for security reasons and would like to keep it hidden.

Comment: Did you name your file `secrets.py`? Pick a different name.

Comment: Do you have secrets.py?  Is it in the same directory as init.py?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to import a package submodule, you're going to have to use an explicit relative import, or specify the fully-qualified module name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) is a module added python stdlib in v3.6. Your code is trying to import `key` from there, which doesn't exists.
You need to use relative import:

```
from .secrets import key
```

But to remove confusion between stdlib modules & your modules, I would suggest you rename your file to something else.